# How do I set ARR affinity for an Azure cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a web role in a cloud service with 2 instances.

I have a function that creates files in one instance and switches to the other mid-function, causing 404 errors because it can't find the files.

In Azure Web Apps, there is a setting in the [Azure Portal](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/06/03/setting-application-request-routing-arr-affinity-for-your-azure-app-service/) to turn ARR Affinity on or off. I don't see anything like that in Azure Cloud Services.

Comment: I'm no Azure expert, but this sounds lika a common cluster setup. I.e. you could store the files that are created on a network drive that is mounted on both servers.

Comment: The files are created using third party software, so I can't control where the files go or even see the code to change it.

Answer (score 0):

For cloud services, you'll need to install it manually by yourself on your startup task of csdef file.
ARR is not installed by default for IIS.

You can refer to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/05/12/setting-up-session-affinitysticky-sessions-using-azure-java-sdk-for-cloud-service/) article for more information (from step 4).